# Tradingview Pine Script : How to find the HLC3 of a lower time frames ? (V5)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

hlc3 is a predefined series float in Pine Script for the timeframe of the current chart.
How do I get the a hlc3 series float of lower timeframe within the current chart?

Say am on a daily chart, my pinescript (V5) code will give me the series float for predefined variable hlc3. I want to to get the hourly series hlc3

```
//(high + low + close)/3
Low1HLC1 = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "1", expression = (high + low + close) / 3)

esa1 = ta.ema(Low1HLC1, n1)
```

I get the error:

> Error at 119:15 Cannot call 'ta.ema' with argument 'source'='Low1HLC1'. An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.

I want to get a series float of lower timeframe hlc3

Answer (score 0):

With the lower time frame data you have to do some extra steps to be able to use it. You'll need to put the data into a new float array and then you can access it. Here's an example on a 5 minute chart requesting the data from a 1 minute chart

```
indicator("My script")

hlc = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, '1', hlc3)
float[] newArray = array.new<float>(5)

if hlc.size() > 0
    for i = 0 to hlc.size() - 1
        newArray.shift()
        newArray.push(hlc.get(i))

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high,str.tostring(newArray.get(0), format.mintick) + ' ' + str.tostring(hlc.get(0), format.mintick))

ma = newArray.avg()
plot(ma)
```

So here I have the same data in both arrays. I left the debug label on so you can see. Then just quickly turned that into a moving average, which looks like what you are trying to do.